# Is there some difference between parsing network and parsing a file?

Tags: c, networking, network-programming, redis, protocols

I am writing a tool to dump redis 's rdb data file. I send a 'sync' command the save as a slave. and then parse the rdb to keys,values.
However, I can not parse the rdb when directly read from the network. It works well when I write the network data to a file and pares the file instead . I don't know why . The code parse the network and the file is completely same.
Is there some difference between parsing network and parsing a file ?

Thanks !

----------------update------------------
Problem solved:
It's my fault , I do not familiar with network programming. I used read system call in a wrong way.
For example:
I want read SIZE bytes from network,I wrote:
`nread = read(fd,buf,SIZE)`
I assumed that the nread is equal to SIZE . This works well for reading file at the most of time but does not work when reading net stream at most of time.
So I use syncRead in redis replication.c instead.
Thanks all of you for helping me  solving the problem !

Comment: It's an IO stream in both cases. Should be no difference. I'd revise your networking code.

Comment: You cannot seek in network streams.

Comment: the obvious question is how do you parse?

Comment: @Jon: indeed, but you shouldn't want to seek when reading .rdb from stream. It's pretty sequential.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: No idea about .rdb so I take your word for it that it can be parsed sequentially. That doesn't mean noone has written code to parse it "wrong" though.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between parsing a network stream and parsing a file. Specifically, in the case of parsing redis dump file, there is never a need to seek forward or backwards. You know before hand the exact number of bytes you have to read, so you can allocate the right amount of memory.

One problem with connecting as a slave via the sync command - Redis server does not close the connection. As soon as the rdb file is transferred, it starts sending incremental commands via the regular redis protocol. If you are unable to detect this transition, you will have parsing errors.

If you still are unable to parse the network stream, perhaps you should provide some code, or paste some exceptions / stack traces.

Having said that, I think it is best to write the dump file to the disk and then parse it. That is the way redis slaves operate right now.

Aside :

I am the author of [redis-rdb-tools](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools), which is a python based parser for the redis dump files. I have documented the [format of the dump file](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/wiki/Redis-RDB-Dump-File-Format), and have a [FAQ entry](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/wiki/FAQs) on how to create a parser in a different language. You may find those links useful.

Comment: thanks for the rdb file format description! By the way, current format version is 6. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Indeed it is, and redis-rdb-tools has had support for it since the day antirez updated it! Can you point me to the incorrect documentation so that I can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: This one, for example: https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/wiki/FAQs. "We have unit tests for versions 2 through 5." Which kinda implies that version 6 is untested.

Comment: Thanks, FAQs updated. We do have tests for version 6 as well, so it was a one character change in the documentation.